# Project source code that follows Microsoft Best Practices

Tags: design-patterns

I would like to know if you know some sites with great source code that follows Microsoft best practices?

By best practice I mean that projects that most likely conforms to say, this documents: http://www.codeplex.com/AppArchGuide
http://apparch.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Pocket%20Guides&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you will find "great source code" (ahem) which follows Microsoft's best practices outside of Microsoft for these reasons:

1. Most of the products will be commercial (-> closed source)
2. To follow Microsoft's development style, you need to be a big company with lots of developers. Most OSS projects are rather small (i.e. a small core team and lots of volunteers).

Comment: Several programmers using Microsoft products follows that document so that document intends for people outside Microsoft to practice good programming styles.  The document applies to projects whether big or small.  Maybe you just misunderstood the concept of best practices.

Comment: I own the book "Writing Solid Code" (which has been translated to "Never Again Bugs" in Germany). It's a bit old but a good read despite the fact that no company ever tortured more users with more bugs ;) So take my answer with a grain of salt :)

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Writing-Solid-Code-Microsofts-Programming/dp/1556155514

Comment: @Greg Bray: M$ is an official acronym for Microsoft: http://www.all-acronyms.com/cat/9/M$/Microsoft/32727

Comment: M$ is NOT an official acronym for Microsoft, it is an acronym used by people that are biased against or critical of Microsoft ( See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M$#Currency_signs_replacing_similar_letters ) MS, MSFT, and Microsoft are the only names used officially by Microsoft. Using M$ in your answer degrades the quality of your response and reflects poorly on our community.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/is-m-for-microsoft-allowed-considered-ok for further discussion.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla, that acronym database categorizes it as "modern slang". That's not official.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Microsoft's own code follows their best practices, so have a look at [Shared Source Initiative](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/sharedsource/default.mspx).

Comment: To be honest, I'm looking code for project source code that can be used by users rather than projects that can be used by developers (i.e. development tools).

Comment: Well, then be honest and edit your question accordingly :-)

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be very hard to find any open source code that complies to Microsoft's standards. You could, however check to see how closely a given project conforms using [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) and [FXCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx) with the default rulesets.

One place I would look is the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), and [programs built using it](http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Software_using_Mono).

Also, [mad-j's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650160/project-source-code-that-follows-microsoft-best-practices/650188#650188) of looking at the shared source initiative, may help, but I would guess that not all of their code strictly follows their guidelines.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood the question.  I'm looking for a site with great source code, not enforcing rules with source code.

Comment: The reason I suggested these tools is that they can be used to compare given source code to the guidelines set forth by Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx and if you don't have VS 2008, download FxCop, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.  The practices site that you mentioned are mostly documents and not source code for Microsoft best practices.  And I don't see the relevance of using FXCop which is a tool to check code.  I'm finding sites with source codes.